# Lavarel - Nested query conditional

Tags: php, laravel

I have a problem in this code

```
$query
        ->where('start_at', '>=', max($campaign->start_at, now()))
        ->where('end_at', '<=', $campaign->end_at)
        ->whereNull('deleted_at')
        ->where('num_posti', '>', function ($query){
            $query
                ->from((new Reservation())->getTable())
                ->whereColumn('id', '=', 'slots.id')
                ->whereNull('deleted_at')
                ->count();
        });
```

The 'slots.id' field doesn't see, but if I execute only the query's first part i see this value.

What is the problem?

Comment: Can you share your  entities ?